# Badblocks not displaying "Pass completed" after finishing

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bad-blocks

This is the command I am running to test a HDD with badblocks:

```
badblocks -b 4096 -c 98304 -w -s /dev/sda1
```

The output is:

```
[root@localhost liveuser]# badblocks -b 4096 -c 98304 -w -s /dev/sda1
Testing with pattern 0x55: done
Reading and comparing: done 
Testing with pattern 0xff: done
Reading and comparing: done 
Testing with pattern 0x00: done
Reading and comparing: done 
[root@localhost liveuser]#
```

Is this correct? Does this mean the drive passed? I thought there would be an output such as "pass completed" or similar. For example this is  question has a different output to mine https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65349/how-to-interpret-badblocks-output

Using fedora 17 live cd

Comment: Your drive is fine.  If you had failures it would have ended with a list of the failed blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `-v` switch (verbose) to get a summary:

```
# badblocks -v -b 4096 -c 1024 -w -s /dev/sdb
Checking for bad blocks in read-write mode
From block 0 to 1023
Testing with pattern 0xaa: done                                                 
Reading and comparing: done                                                 
Testing with pattern 0x55: done                                                 
Reading and comparing: done                                                 
Testing with pattern 0xff: done                                                 
Reading and comparing: done                                                 
Testing with pattern 0x00: done                                                 
Reading and comparing: done                                                 
Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
#
```